# Article got accepted into PRL -- do I pay the costs?

Tags: publications, physics, publishers, fees

Last week we got an article accepted into PRL (Physical Review Letters). As is standard, they afterwards sent out an email saying

> To help defray editorial and production expenses, APS, a
>   not-for-profit, society publisher, expects authors of manuscripts to
>   pay appropriate publication charges; publication charges are
>   contributions from authors' institutions to the cost of disseminating
>   research results and should be regarded as an essential and proper
>   part of their research budget.  You are requested to make a payment of
>   $765 toward the cost of disseminating your research results.  However,
>   the inability to pay this charge will not affect the publication
>   process of your manuscript.

So they say they expect us to pay, but at the same time they say the publication process continues independently of whether this happens.

What is the 'proper'/'sensible' thing to do? What is commonly done?

Comment: It seems to me that they are making an exception for "poor" researchers and institutions (e.g., in the developed world). I think, assuming you're funded, they expect you to pay and charge this to your project(s).

Comment: @ThomasKing: That’s an answer. Please post it as such.

Comment: @aeismail This is really an opinion question. It is clear you do not have to pay, and many groups, even with funding, do not. See also: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/89880/what-is-the-benefit-of-voluntary-page-charges

Comment: IEEE is also a not-for-profit, but I see no reason to pay them.

Comment: @user2768 If everybody thinks the same way, the research dissemination venues wouldn't improve, I suppose. If the author is funded, then why not use it.

Comment: @Coder No free lunch. $1000 given to a publisher to cover their editing budget means $1000 less for your scientific research, or $1000 less to support a graduate student. Just because somebody is funded doesn't mean they have a infinite amount of money.

Comment: @user2768 I do understand your point and I do strongly agree with this. But, there has to be a trade-off to be maintained. The funding budgets have various heads of accounts such as student fellowship head, equipment head, ..., publication or conference contingency. On that aspect, I said it. Anyway, I am not sure of the kind of funding though.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! @Coder perhaps you can post your case as an answer, and we can let the community 'decide' in terms of upvotes?

Comment: @Coder I see IEEE as part of the problem. With unpaid academics (as authors, editors, reviewers, ...) and services such as arxiv, I no longer see a need for IEEE to act as a publisher (and I certainly don't see a need for them to claim ownership of conference names). Of course, arxiv requires funding, but we'd see reductions: -$170 (editorial and production aspects), -$80 (waiver premium), -$20 billing, ... Source of costs: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/52009/22768

Comment: I recommend you do not give money to the APS.  It should be easy to find a better use of your money.  I think they provide little value to the physics community, except that they are not as bad at publishing as Elsevier.

Answer (score 6):

*What are your options?* You can pay or delete the email.

If you pay, your group will have $765 less. That's the only difference in outcomes. These charges are completely voluntary and have no effect on anything if you choose not to pay. In my experience, you'll never hear about this again. You will not have to justify your decision.

*What do most people do?* From my observations, the majority of groups simply don't pay voluntary charges, regardless of available funds.

*What should you do?* This is a matter of opinion. You (or the PI with the money) should decide whether APS deserves a $765 donation for the purposes they state, or whether it can be put to better use at your institution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pay or not pay, it is entirely up to you. But you should remember that someone must pay for the journals to exist. On the one hand, if you think that journals are useless, don't pay, end of story. Maybe the future is in the arXive? But even for the arXive to exist, someone pays - check their web page. On the other hand, if you think that journals are useful, think twice if may be, may be, it is worth paying anyhow. Today, journals are under enormous pressure financially, they have to remodel their financing to accommodate (perfectly justified) requests for open access and departures from paper. And, hey, never ever pay any Elsevier journal - these guys turn up huge profits by exploiting unpaid labour of authors, referees, and editors.

Answer (score 0):

The funding budgets have various heads of accounts such as student fellowship head, equipment head, printing, traveling, journal publication or conference contingency.

Assuming that your project also has such division of heads, you could spend your money for publication. Plus, you could ask for a waiver from the publication venue citing suitable situation. They listen (most of the time).